# grails startup error when run-app

Tags: grails, run-app

When I copied my old project from my old computer and typed grails run-app in project folder, I get the following error:

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
G:\Windows NT 5.0 Workstation Profile\.grails\2.0.0\projects\timesheet\plugins\g
orm-labs-0.8.5\src\groovy\GormLabsHibernateCriteriaBuilder.groovy: 35: The retur
n type of java.lang.Object order(java.lang.String) in grails.orm.GormLabsHiberna
teCriteriaBuilder is incompatible with org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.api.Cr
iteria order(java.lang.String) in grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
. At [35:5]  @ line 35, column 5.
       Object order(String propertyName) {
       ^

1 error
```

Can anyone tell me what this relates to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You said you just copied the project, but you must have at least partially upgraded it since your error shows that you're using Grails 2.0.0. The error message has to do with the Gorm Labs plugin, which has been abandoned for over a year and is unlikely to be compatible with newer versions of Grails. I'd remove that and any usage of it and see where you get from there.